# Mysql: Swap data for different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose a table `fruits` that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| id |    name    |   color   | calories |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | apple      | red       | 20       |
| 2  | orange     | orange    | 10       |
| 3  | grapes     | green     | 5        |
| 4  | bananas    | yellow    | 15       |
| 5  | plum       | purple    | 25       |
------------------------------------------
```

How can I **swap** the values of a row, with another, leaving the id number intact?

Example:

```
SWAP ROW WITH ID "5" WITH ROW WITH ID "2"
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------
| id |    name    |   color   | calories |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | apple      | red       | 20       |
| 2  | plum       | purple    | 25       |
| 3  | grapes     | green     | 5        |
| 4  | bananas    | yellow    | 15       |
| 5  | orange     | orange    | 10       |
------------------------------------------
```

Note that all the values are intact except for the id. 
I need to do this with a really large list of values, so I need a one-liner, or at most, something that doesn't require the creation of temporary tables, and things like that.

Note: id is unique

Thank you

Comment: like any other swap operation in almost any other programming language. copy record #1's data into temporary storage, copy record #2's data into record #1. then copy data from temporary storage into record #2. There's no 'swap' operation built into sql to do what you want in a single neat query.

Comment: or write a script that does the same thing (as @MarcB 's comment)

Comment: Could the temporary storage be a new row in the table? I need to make sure that row is deleted when the copy operation is done, though

Comment: it can be whatever you want. you just need a place to store at least one of those records while you're copying data between them. I wouldn't use a record in the same table, though. suddenly you'll end up with a duplicate (say) apple record, throwing off any counts/inventories/etc.. for the brief moment that temporary record exists.

Comment: if it's a new row in the table then I guess you would have to find a unique id for that everytime, which is why writing a script would make it simpler or as @MarcB suggested, store it in another place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a join inequality to line up the rows you want to swap:

```
update fruit a
 inner join fruit b on a.id <> b.id
   set a.color = b.color,
       a.name = b.name,
       a.calories = b.calories
 where a.id in (2,5) and b.id in (2,5)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27318a/5

Comment: To swap two values I tried with "a.color=b.color, b.color=a.color" and it unexpectedly worked. Is it "normal" for sql to not require an intermediate variable contrary to a normal programming language, or is it just a specific case?

Comment: @xtian take a look at the updated fiddle.  Observe that the update can be re-written as a select statement.  Running that select you should see that there is indeed an "intermediate variable" in the form of the table output produced which has columns for original values and columns with values swapped.  This is the "source" an update statement will execute from when it writes to the target table.  So, its no different than a normal programming language.  Your intermediate variables are implied in the update expression itself.

Comment: @cocogorilla Thank you. I appreciate your complex thought.

Comment: I tried this, but got two identical rows. In the answer by fthiella the id of 'in' are mirrored but here they are same way.

Comment: @cocogorilla it looks like SqlFiddle updated and the link is broken. Don't suppose you have the version re-written as a select statement?

Answer (score 9):

Since ID is unique, it is difficult to just swap the IDs, it's easier to swap the column contents. A query like this might be what you need:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
  ON (t1.id, t2.id) IN ((1,5),(5,1))
SET
  t1.color = t2.color,
  t1.name = t2.name,
  t1.calories = t2.calories
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b156/1).

Comment: that's a neat way of doing it :)

Comment: @fthiella beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to store values temporarily without using a temp table or a dummy row in your fruit table:

```
SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit WHERE id = 2 INTO @name, @color, @calories;

UPDATE fruit AS f1, fruit AS f2
SET
 f1.name = f2.name, f2.name = @name,
 f1.color = f2.color, f2.color = @color,
 f1.calories = f2.calories, f2.calories = @calories
WHERE (f1.id, f2.id) = (2, 5);
```

Here's another solution that uses a dummy id value:

```
UPDATE fruit SET id = 0 WHERE id = 5;
UPDATE fruit SET id = 5 WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE fruit SET id = 2 WHERE id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your operations are based on ***ID***, and you want to swap entire rows, a fancy way of swapping ***UNIQUE IDs*** is to start numbering them at 1, and use 0 as a temporary value.

Another way of performing this is using an unsigned column, and using a designated value (ie.: -1) for temporary. I wouldn't really recommend the latter, as we are effectively *wasting space* with this method. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html for more details.