# Mysql Swap data between rows using a dummy table

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose a table fruits that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| id |    name    |   color   | calories |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | apple      | red       | 20       |
| 2  | orange     | orange    | 10       |
| 3  | grapes     | green     | 5        |
| 4  | bananas    | yellow    | 15       |
| 5  | plum       | purple    | 25       |
------------------------------------------
```

How can I swap the values of a row, with another, leaving the id number intact?

Example:

SWAP ROW WITH ID "5" WITH ROW WITH ID "2"

Result:

```
------------------------------------------
| id |    name    |   color   | calories |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | apple      | red       | 20       |
| 2  | plum       | purple    | 25       |
| 3  | grapes     | green     | 5        |
| 4  | bananas    | yellow    | 15       |
| 5  | orange     | orange    | 10       |
------------------------------------------
```

Note that all the values are intact except for the id. Note that this is a very large list in reality.

Note: id, and some of the values of the table are unique.
Note2: There's a question posted on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433666/mysql-swap-data-for-different-rows), but it requires not using a dummy table, so I'd like to see the solution when the table has unique values other than just id.

Thank you

Comment: These and all you have to give a try and  ask as a question here

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433666/mysql-swap-data-for-different-rows

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE fruit a, fruit b  
   SET a.color = b.color,
       a.name = b.name,
       a.calories = b.calories
 WHERE a.id <> b.id 
   AND a.id in (2,5) 
   AND b.id in (2,5);
```

Comment: i think its not good to copy / paste without giving credit. Here is an original answer with the exact query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433666/mysql-swap-data-for-different-rows

Answer (score 0):

The following statements will work.

```
UPDATE fruits SET id=6 where id=2
UPDATE fruits SET id=2 where id=5
UPDATE fruits SET id=5 where id=6
```