# Rearrange table row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to rearrange mysql table rows for example

```
column1 | column2 | column3
1         abc       abc
2         def       def
3         ghi       ghi
```

after some procedure

```
column1 | column2 | column3
2         def       def
1         abc       abc
3         ghi       ghi
```

means randomly rearrange existing table

NOTE: I cant use rand() in mysql query for some reason

Comment: why can't you use rand() in mysql ?

Comment: There is no order in your table, ordering is only controlled by ORDER BY clause during a query, underlying order cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: I built application to display quotes but one problem is that in table author_name not stored randomly and when i use RAND() then every time i got random quotes but i don't want so i can't use RAND()

Comment: ok then refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433666/mysql-swap-data-for-different-rows

Comment: If it helps then pls accept the and.So that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

**For selecting a single row, you can use this method:**

For a I suppose `column1` is the Primary Key of the table.

Now I use another method to solve this issue.

```
SELECT MIN(column1), MAX(column1) FROM tablename;
```

Fetch the result into `$a`

```
//php code

$column1=rand($a[0],$a[1]);

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column1>='$column1' LIMIT 1
```

**Now you may try something like[I am not sure about the result]:**

```
SELECT * FROM tablename  ORDER BY column1=RAND(0,3);
```

Here 3 is the maximum range expected for `column1`.